# C# awaitable collection

Tags: c#, asynchronous, collections, task

Is there a standard way to await for a collection to be marked as complete by another task (thread?)  I am looking for something like `await collection.Completion.Task`

So far I found the following approaches:

- Use a `TaskCompletionSource` variable (needs to be shared with the other task/thread)
- Use a `BlockingCollection` and do a `while(!collection.IsAddingCompleted) {}` (not async)
- Use a `BufferBlock<T>` from TPL Dataflow and do an `await bufferBlock.Completion.Task` (probably lots of overhead?)
- Use an `ObservableCollection` (not async)
- Any other?

All thoughts appreciated

**EDIT: Adding scenario to give more context**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<int>();
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        //This thread represents an independent process which will populate the list
        new Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200); // do work
                    list.Add(i);
                }
                tcs.SetResult(true);
                Thread.Sleep(2000); //do more work
                Console.WriteLine("The End -- Press Enter");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        ).Start();

        //This task awaits for the list to be populated
        new Task(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(300); //do work
            await tcs.Task;
            Console.WriteLine("List count = " + list.Count);
        }).Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean, to be honest - any reason you don't want to just have a `Task<List<T>>` (or whatever collection you mean)? Giving more context would really help.

Comment: The collection is populated by an independent thread responding to signals (e.g. web server)

Comment: You seem to be a bit confused by the relationship between tasks and threads, and I find it odd that you think that observable collections are not asynchronous. In what way are they not asynchronous? What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: Afaik ObservableCollection does not have any method/property that can be used with await.  I already have an `async` code segment and I don't like the idea of mixing it with an event handler tied to an ObservableCollection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a standard way to await for a collection to be marked as complete by another task?

You can use any kind of "signal" for this. Since this is just a one-time signal, `TaskCompletionSource<T>` would be fine. The fact that it's a collection-completed signal is immaterial. Though, as you found, some collections do have this built-in.

To address each of your questions:

- `TaskCompletionSource<T>` - the most straightforward, IMO, since it can be used with any kind of collection.
- `BlockingCollection<T>` - You wouldn't want to use `BlockingCollection`, but you can use an [`AsyncProducerConsumerQueue` or `AsyncCollection`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx), which are the same abstraction but allowing asynchronous waits.
- `BufferBlock<T>` - Also fine. A lot of people use `BufferBlock<T>` as an async-compatible producer/consumer queue.
- `ObservableCollection<T>` - not an option since it doesn't have the notion of "completion".
- Others - If your collection is "push-based", you can use `IObservable<T>` and just `await` it.

Comment: Thank you!  `AsyncCollection` looks great but I'd prefer something part of the standard libraries.  `IObservable<T>` sounds interesting.  Isn't `BufferBlock<T>` somewhat of an overkill?  TPL Dataflow seems more about passing messages than storing values...

Comment: Sure, `BufferBlock<T>` has some overhead, but it's not extremely heavy. If you want a MS-written async-compatible producer/consumer queue, it's the only one AFAIK. Though I suppose you could use `IObservable<T>`'s `ToListAsync` to kinda-sorta be an "async collection".